# Next move in The Times Sudoku #12583

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

I'm completely stuck on how to move on with this Sudoku - what's the next number?

[image: Sudoku]

It's from *The Times* puzzles - [number 12583](https://www.thetimes.co.uk/puzzles/sudoku-no-12583-fiendish-ksw3zhsz5) on 13/08/21

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible next action involves the fifth row.

> R5C2 can only be a 2 or a 5.
>  R5C4 can also only be a 2 or a 5.
>  This "naked pair" means that in the other locations in row 5 there is no 2 or 5.
>  In particular, R5C5 can now only be a 1.

Further deductions are all straightforward.